# generate httpbasicauth in C

Tags: c, http, authentication, https

in Python there is a method "requests.auth.httpbasicauth" that generates the authentication code, is there a similar function in C - have been looking but can not find anything - i need to generate it dynamically in C.

thank you for your help.

Comment: You should probably look at OpenSSL or one of its ilk (though I'm not certain that the necessary method(s) are directly provided).  You might need to look at the Apache web server code.  It isn't something you will be able to do casually.

Comment: cool, i am using BearSSL - i will see if they have something like it. Thank you for your response